# Backupset server name on dev server shows Prod server name

Tags: sql-server, database-backups

I'm using the following code to determine the last time a database was backed up:

```
SELECT
   bus.server_name AS servername
   ,sdb.Name AS DatabaseName
   ,COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), MAX(bus.backup_finish_date), 101), '-') AS LastBackUpTime
FROM sys.sysdatabases sdb
LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset bus
ON bus.database_name = sdb.name
WHERE 
   bus.backup_start_date >= DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 1, GETDATE()), 0) -- Previous day at midnight.
   AND bus.backup_start_date < DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0) -- Today at midnight.
GROUP BY 
   sdb.Name
   ,bus.server_name
```

And it *appears* to show the data I'm looking for, but if I run this code on a development server, for example, it shows its corresponding production server as the `bus.server_name` value.
I'm trying to understand why it's showing a production server' name and not itself.  I may not be understanding how the backupset table is getting its value.
I know I can use `@@ServerName` for that value but I'm not sure if that is correct way to get that value.

Comment: i'm assuming you restored from prod to dev, no?

Comment: Yes.  That is correct.

Comment: I should have specified, did you restore system databases too or just the user database? This should show the server that took the backup, but that wouldn't follow the backup to another server you restore to

Comment: Just a user database.  We'll call it user_Database1 from Production.  It's no on a development server with the same name.  We really don't backup our dev databases but totally by accident I ran the above code on our dev server and that's how I stumbled upon this question.
I did a test backup just a few minutes ago and it shows the dev server' name.  It's just very odd the prod server for that database is showing as the backup server name. Unless the server name is being shown from the backup set which is from production.  In which case I think I just answered my question.  Thoughts?

Comment: is *It's no on a development server* supposed to be *not* or *now*? Are you sure your query connection wasn't still on the prod server? I'd restore from PROD again, and then test this again. I just can't see how that happens. Even with log shipping and AlwaysOn i can't replicate this.

Comment: Confirmed.  I'm on my dev server.  Quite honestly that was the first thing I verified.  PLUS I went one step further and added 
    @@Servername as HostServerName 
in my code and got 2 different server names.
"HostServerName" showed my Dev box
"Servername" showed the Prod box.
Again...I think I may have answered my own question.  The databases in question were last backed up on the Prod machine even though they were restored to the dev box.  Therefore the BACKUPSET (which my query is hitting) is showing the server name backed up.

Comment: Very odd because I do the same thing but it doesnt show my prod server. But maybe something different with how you are taking the backup (specifically new backup set it just copy only may have different results)

Comment: I’d post this on dba.stackexchange. You are probably right but there are some power DBAs on that forum

Comment: What settings do you change in the Backup Database "wizard"?  For the most part all of ours are default settings.

Comment: I dont use the wizard often but it would depend on your use case. You may want to look into ola hallengren scripts too

Answer (score 0):

This is confirmed.

If you restore a database from one server to another, but never back it up, and run the code I have above, it will show the server name from the original server it was backed up from.

***BUT*** if you then do a backup of that same database, it will then show the current server it was backed up from which is what I expected.